# Symbolic link to NAS

Tags: symbolic-link, nas

I love the "sticky notes"- program xpad. Would it be possible to use the command `ln -s` to link it's config folder to a shared folder on a NAS drive, to have the `xpad-sessions` synced on all my local computers, and if so, what happens when I'am not connected to the LAN and add a note; will the symbolic link break and never get re-linked?

Answer (score 1):

When a program tries to access a symbolic link the kernel silently translates it so the program is actually accessing the target. You could indeed make your `~/.xpadconf` (for example; I don't know where its actual config file is) a symbolic link to a config file on a NAS. Example:

```
ln -s /mnt/NAS/.xpadconf ~/.xpadconf
```

Note that `ln` can only link to somewhere on your filesystem, so you would first have to mount the NAS to your local filesystem (e.g. `smbfs`, `sshfs`, `nfs`). Then you can link to it. If `xpad` stores notes in a different file from config settings you'll have to mount+link that as well (again, I'm not familiar with the program).

If the NAS is not mounted, I expect `xpad` will throw an error because it cannot read the file. If you unmount the NAS while `xpad` is open then try to save a note, you will either get an error because it cannot write to the file, or `xpad` will hang due to the broken network mount and you'll have to kill it.

As long as you only open `xpad` and save notes while the NAS is mounted, it should work as you want. I expect you won't have any issues with just viewing notes even if you unmount the NAS with `xpad` open.